# SSIS Script Task Error in C#

Tags: c#, ssis, msbi, script-task

I want to read a Excel file from Script Task.
Add below code in the C# script file. 
[image]

when execute the script it gives the below error.

[image]

help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Have you [debuged the script task](https://www.sqlshack.com/script-task-debugging-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/) to determine where it fails?

Comment: You haven't posted the error.  You've posted the stack trace.  Look for something in the output with the word "Error" in it, and post that.